# How can I make listview clickable when custom adapter view is used?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, clickable

I know this question is asked several times and I tried to solve according the other solution but in vain. I used customAdapterView with listview. I have also set clickable in the xml. But it's not working.

**My question is what's the error that listview is not being clickable?**

**Another interesting matter catches my eye that if i start any id name with "list....." during findViewby resoruce id or case - the "l" alphabet automatically becomes captial. Why it happens?

The following portion is inside of onCreate method:-

```
    uddin= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.uddin_name_array);
body=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.uddin_body_array);    
    prof = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.prof_name_array);    


     ListView listView= findViewById(R.id.uddinListView);
            listView.setClickable(true);
        listView.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_list_view,uddin,prof));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 

{

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

Intent  intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ReadingUddinActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);}
}
        );
```

Comment: Is there anyone to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I have found the culprit in the code. It was in the xml code. My Java code worked without error. But it was not clickable because of a rating bar in the custom adapter view.

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:numStars="2" />
```

When i assign the style as

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar"
```

list item prevents to become clickable. 
but if i assign the style as

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
```

or,

```
     style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Indicator"
```

it works fine.  I don't know why the first one doesn't work. Expert may find the reasons.